# HP 2410 printer shared on Winwows XP not visible on Ubuntu's network

Tags: 12.04, printing, samba, hp

I have Ubuntu 12.04 and HP 2410 printer shared on Windows XP.

Problem is that under Ubuntu are visible only network printers, but not printers shared on XP.

I installed HP Device Manager, and shared printers are still not visible.

Also, I noticed that I cannot find shared printers, like I can find shared Windows XP directories.

Can you tell me what did I miss to get this to work.

Just to mention that printing is possible from other Windows XP workstation. And of course, Samba is running under Ubuntu.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I made it work.

On next link is very good explanation how to setup samba under Ubuntu:

http://www.sitepoint.com/ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-file-sharing-with-samba/

Thing I was missing before is part with configuration of Winbind. When I made it as it is described there, it started to work.